# Printing 2 Python Pandas DataFrame in HTML Tables in iPython Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook

**Question:** How can you print 2 DataFrame tables together from 1 iPython Notebook row, such that both tables are displayed in the pretty table format?

The following prints just the second one, and `print df.head()` does not produce a pretty table.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=pd.date_range('20150101', periods=6), columns=list('ABCD'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=pd.date_range('20150101', periods=6), columns=list('WXYZ'))


df.head()
df2.head()
```

[image]

The following does not produce the pretty table needed:

```
print df.head()
print df2.head()
```

Comment: Are you wanting the bottom answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966780/pandas-show-results-of-apply-next-to-original-dataframe if so I'll close as duplicate

Comment: df.head(), df2.head()

Comment: or you can use `print`

Comment: @joris `print df.head()` doesnt produce a pretty table

Comment: or ``from IPython.display import display``, and then use `display(df.head())`

Comment: @joris you should post that as an answer

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873127/print-dataframe-as-table-in-ipython-notebook/28507257#28507257

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the IPython notebook, only the result of the last line of a cell is shown, unless it is explicitly printed or displayed.

Some options:

- Put the second `df.head()` in the next cell
- Use `print df` to explicitly print the dataframe -> but, this gives the text representation instead of html representation
- Use `display(df)` to explicitly display the dataframe, this *will* give the same html representation as how a dataframe is shown by default. You need the following import for this:

  ```
  from IPython.display import display
  ```